# Macport self update fail mountain lion. Earlier it was working fine

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macports

Macport self update fail mountain lion. Earlier it was working fine. Here is output of

```
sudo port -d selfupdate
```

I think it broke after i installed the Mountain lion update. Before 2 weeks it was working fine. I installed the mountain lion java update, Xcode update and other updates. Is that update causing problem?

```
DEBUG: Copying /Users/admin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10
DEBUG: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed
```

Comment: as the error message says, you have a network connection error: the `port` program can't reach the macports.org host. Try again later.

Comment: @MattDMo internet connection is working fine. i tried it several time its showing the same error.